# VS Code Markdown Previewer Not Rendering Tables At All

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I am using VS Code v1.86.2 on Ubuntu 22.04.

I am trying to write markdown files, but am having trouble with getting the VS Code Markdown Preview to render tables correctly.

I have tried the following, and they all justrender as a single line stream, like a paragraph.

```
|| Head 1 | Head 2 ||
| Col1    | Col 2   |


| Head 1 | Head 2 |
| +----+ | +----+ |
| Col1   | Col 2  |


| Head 1 | Head 2 |
+--------+--------+
| Col1   | Col 2  |


+--------+--------+
| Head 1 | Head 2 |
+--------+--------+
| Col1   | Col 2  |
+--------+--------+


| Head 1 | Head 2 |
|--------|--------|
| Col1   | Col 2  |
```

The only form that kind of works is :

```
Head 1     Head 2
---------- -----------
Col1       Col2
```

I'd also like to know how to achieve a 'horizontal' table (if that's the right term), whereby the first column is the heading, and is shaded, or in bold text:

```
| Head 1 | Col 1 |
| Head 2 | Col2  |
```

I'm thinking there is a particular extension I need to install, but which one? There are hundreds of them to choose from, and most seem to be utilities to help space out the tables when writing the document, and do not help with the previewer.

Comment: the fifth one you showed works. use GitHub flavoured Markdown tables.

Comment: @starball Thanks for that, I searched for gitHub flavoured markdown tables and found this page https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/organizing-information-with-tables. This solved the problem. Thanks.